# Layer KML usando OpenLayers3

Tags: ajax, postgresql, postgis, openlayers-3, kml

Estou iniciando em Openlayers e estou com um problema na visualização de polígonos em mapas.
Tenho um conjunto de polígonos sendo retornados de uma consulta no banco de dados (postgres/postgis). Este conjunto de polígonos é passado via json por uma requisição ajax para o frontend onde eu pretendo usar a biblioteca OpenLayers3 para exibir esses polígonos em um mapa.

Exemplo do retorno como KML:

```
{st_askml=<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-53.460269936027402,-24.954734829872194 -53.460072335178054,-24.954744520125182 -53.460093771307605,-24.955104793997403 -53.460291372725941,-24.955095103672289 -53.460269936027402,-24.954734829872194</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>}
{st_askml=<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-53.459896169834188,-24.955114484062349 -53.459874734273619,-24.9547542101181 -53.459701833437066,-24.954762688648493 -53.459723268499758,-24.955122962655768 -53.459896169834188,-24.955114484062349</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>}
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de criar a camada vetorial com esses polígonos utilizando OL3?
Salvando o conjunto de polígonos em um arquivo e utilizando este arquivo como source para a camada? 
Usando o próprio json como source para a camada? (existe esta possibilidade?)
e como ficaria a sintaxe dessa layer em OL3?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos assumir que seus polígonos sejam compostos por listas de coordenadas `lat` x `lng`, por exemplo:

```
var a =[
    {
        "lng": 106.972534,
        "lat": -6.147714
    },
    {
        "lng": 106.972519,
        "lat": -6.133398
    },
    {
        "lng": 106.972496,
        "lat": -6.105892
    }
]
```

A primitiva `geom.Polygon()` aceita coleções onde o último item da lista é equivalente ao primeiro (para que seu polígono seja propriamente fechado) e onde latitude e longitude são definidas em uma coleção de valores primitivos (`[lng, lat]`).

Você precisa fechar o seu polígono, usando as mesmas coordenadas iniciais como finais:

```
a.push(a[0]);
```

Após isso, transforme a coleção inicial de membros complexos para coleções primitivas:

```
var b = a.map(function(item) {
    return [item.lng, item.lat];
});
```

Após isso, crie o objeto via inicialização:

```
var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([b]);
```

Finalmente, para mostrar o polígono você deve utilizar um wrap do tipo `feature()` e adicioná-lo a uma *layer* de vetores, que é então adicionada ao mapa:

```
var feature = new ol.Feature(polygon);

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource });

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

(Adaptado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210362/open-layers-3-how-to-draw-a-polygon-programmically)